# NavigationService.ClearHistory or ClearCache is not clearing previous page from cache

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml, template10

I would like to clear the entire navigation history (including previous page) when I navigate to a particular page. So I am writing the following code in OnNavigated method of that particular Page type.

```
Shell.HamburgerMenu.NavigationService.ClearCache();
Shell.HamburgerMenu.NavigationService.ClearHistory();
this.Frame.BackStack.Clear();
BootStrapper.Current.NavigationService.ClearCache();
BootStrapper.Current.NavigationService.ClearHistory();
```

above method clearing all the navigation history except previous visited page from the cache.

We need to clear the previous visited page also along with other pages.

Please let us know how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
var currentFrame = this.GetRootFrame();
if (currentFrame != null && currentFrame.CanGoBack)
    currentFrame.BackStack.RemoveAt(currentFrame.BackStackDepth);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are calling 
`Shell.HamburgerMenu.NavigationService.ClearCache() / ClearHistory().` You just never know when that whole line of code could change and you would be left having to go back later to change it.

Inheriting `INavigable` or `ViewModelBase` from the MVVM folder it will have the overrides you can call

```
//NavigationService comes from ViewModelBase.... Template10.Mvvm namespace
if(NavigationService.CanGoBack)
   NavigationService.ClearHistory();
```

`NavigationService` is initialized at the start of the application.

I use the above 2 lines of code to exactly what you are asking, it works as expected.  It prevents a user in my case from back navigating to a normal screen from a login screen

as for the cache side of the equation turn off cache on each page. At present I don't believe we have a global for that in T10 or if there well ever be one.

The code the previous answer posted is the more or less the exact code that is in the `ClearHistory() / ClearCache() methods`

n.b.  `ClearCache` is now obsolete in current code branch, on the `NavigationService` for T10